# How to STUFF values in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a classic ASP online form to submit and insert data into this table. This form will insert multiple rows into a table. The form will gather some checkboxes and insert `1` for checked and `0` for unchecked on `Status` column. 
The radio button will store as the names (Jenny, Peter, etc.). 1 `MenuOption` column.

For instance, if I checked Jenny radio button, then it should insert Jenny for all rows in that transaction. However,it inserts only at unchecked at Status (0). How do I create a SQL to select Jenny to display for all `Refnumber` (unique). My query is below but it won't work.

```
ID   Refnumber   MenuOption   Status
------------------------------------
01   12121313    Jenny        0
02   12121313                 1
03   12121313    Jenny        0
04   12121313                 1

05   28273882    Peter        0
06   28273882                 1
07   28273882    Peter        0
08   28273882                 1

SELECT  ID, Refnumber, isnull(MenuOption,'') as MenuOption, Status
ID = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ID
           FROM Report b 
           WHERE b.Refnumber = a.Refnumber 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Report a
GROUP BY  ID, Refnumber,MenuOption,Status
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: `STUFF` has nothing to do with this, it's all about `FOR XML PATH`. All `STUFF` does here is remove leading `', '` from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT distinct Refnumber, isnull(MenuOption,'') as MenuOption, Status, 
       ConcatIds = stuff(ConcatIds,1,1,'')
FROM Report a
cross apply (SELECT ', ' + cast(ID as varchar(100))
              FROM Report b 
               WHERE b.Refnumber = a.Refnumber 
               --and b.Status = a.Status --not sure if this is needed.
               FOR XML PATH('')) cs (ConcatIds)
```

Comment: I got this error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int.

Comment: @JennyTran - Check the updated code. Also those are fairly simple issues, you should try and resolve it.

Comment: It worked. I have one more question, how do I create a query to fill values "Jenny and Peter" at MenuOption, where Status = 1 ? Thanks.